# Сборка qt-4.8.7 64-битным компилятором под Windows

Tags: c++, windows, mingw, qt4, x86-64

Понадобилась 64-битная версия Qt4 под Windows.
Не получается скомпилировать Qt. Конфигурация проходит без ошибок.
Пробовал, как 64-битным mingw, так и компилятором от Майкрософт.
Выдается одна и та же ошибка:

```
c:\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.7>nmake
Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 14.00.24210.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
        C:\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.7\bin\qmake C:/qt-everywhere-opensou
rce-src-4.8.7/\projects.pro  -o Makefile -spec win32-msvc2015
Could not find mkspecs for your QMAKESPEC(win32-msvc2015) after trying:
        C:\Qt\Qt-4.8.7_64bit\mkspecs
Error processing project file: C:/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.7//projects.p
ro
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'C:\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.7\bin\qmake.EXE'
 : return code '0x3'
Stop.
```

Answer (score 1):

-spec win32-msvc2015 - флаг, его можно(и имхо нужно) подправить, вы пытаетесь компилировать 15 студией, Qt версии 4.7 наверное просто не знает, что такая есть...

На сайте Qt они компилят 10. Так что думаю можно полазить и посмотреть, какие значения этого флага допустимы. Вот она вам и говорит, что

```
"Could not find mkspecs for your QMAKESPEC(win32-msvc2015) after trying: C:\Qt\Qt-4.8.7_64bit\mkspecs"
```

Если же это принципиально, компилировать под 2015 студию, вот инструкция на англ, там действительно надо править этот mkspecs. Если проблемы с англ( 0-0  ) то могу перевести, если надо будет и попросите.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32848962/how-to-build-qt-4-8-6-with-visual-studio-2015-without-official-support

Comment: Спасибо. По данному руководству не получилось скомпилять.
Патч установил с помощью питоновской утилиты patch.py. Правда, не на все 100% в этом уверен, т.к. утилита ничего не вывела в консоль. В 3 пункте изменения делать не пришлось, т.к. нужный файл уже был с нужными настройками. В 4 пункте пришлось только добавить (QMAKESPEC)" == "win32-msvc2015" в 27 строку... 
nmake выдает ту же ошибку :(
Обратите внимание, я собираю версию 4.8.7, там уже как-бы есть поддержка MSVC-2015

Comment: Попробовал собрать 4.8.6 - тоже не получилось.
Чего-то явно не хватает в настройках проекта.

Answer (score 1):

Судя по всему, собрать Qt-4.8 с помощью msvc, который идет с бесплатной студией Express, вряд ли удастся. Т.к. платной студии у меня нет, то пытался собрать Qt4 с помощью MinGW-64, и тоже безрезультатно, были ошибки при сборке.

Но есть другое решение. Может кому пригодиться.

Можно установить **msys2**, в котором есть пакетный менеджер pacman, через который можно поставить все необходимое.

```
pacman --needed -S git mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc base-devel
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-qt4
```

также можно поставить qt5:

```
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-qt5
```

Одновременно qt5 и qt4 установлены быть не могут, но это не проблема, т.к. установка занимает около 2 минут.
Найти в сети работающую Qt5 для 64-битного компилятора еще не проблема, а вот с qt4 я облазил очень много сайтов, и нигде не было работающего решения.
Надеюсь, кому-то поможет.